# nodejs failed but bash doesn't stop even I have set -e

Tags: node.js, bash, jenkins, npm

I run a script in nodejs that trigger by bash that run by Jenkins pipeline.

The problem is the pipeline doesn't stop when the error happens. it should not run "echo git add ."

I add `set -e` - but seems that not work in this case.

What I can do to stop the execute in bash because error in the npm/node?

In Jenkins:

```
 stage('Deploy') {
  sh './scripts/deploy.sh'
 }
```

In deploy.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
npm run prepare-version

echo "git add ."
```

In package.json:

```
"scripts": { "prepare-version": "node ./scripts/prepare.js" }
```

prepare.js:

```
 (async() => { 
   throw new Error('bug!!!');
 })();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your node.js file failed, though bash script executed it succesfully. Read and compare status code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
npm run prepare-version

[[ $? != 0 ]] && exit;
echo 'git add .'
```

Comment: this is not working because nodejs process exit with 0 when I throw the error - for some reason. I don't want to use try..catch and process.exit(1). there is a solution in bash side?

Comment: You may add `process.on('unhandledRejection', error => { process.exit(1) }` then.